# Does Manhattan path finding supports diagonal movement?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

Can someone explain whether diagonal movement is supported in Manhattan Distance Metric?

Comment: What have you searched before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) must never overestimate the distance.

Consider a start of 0,0 and a destination of 10,10.

The Manhattan distance metric is 10+10=20, which is an overestimate of the true distance if diagonal moves are allowed.

Therefore the Manhattan distance is not an admissible heuristic for A* when diagonal movement is allowed.